# Setting custom Post-Login Destinations based on user ROLES using spring security

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I want to set custom Post-Login Destinations based on user ROLES in my application. for example :
If a form login isn't prompted by an attempt to access a protected resource, I want to show different pages, based on different roles.
by using target-url I can't do this.
how can I do this by using Spring security ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spring Security 3.0, you can implement a custom [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) (usually by extending `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`), and configure `<form-login>` to use it with `authentication-success-handler-ref` attribute.