# Can i use one Login page to redirect different page with Spring 3.0 Security..?

Tags: spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting custom Post-Login Destinations based on user ROLES using spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818055/setting-custom-post-login-destinations-based-on-user-roles-using-spring-security)

I am doing my project in Java using Spring. I am using spring security in my project.

My problem is that , depending upon the role that is ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADMIN i want to redirect them to different pages.
It means that if Admin is logged in then he should redirect to one page and if normal user is logged in then to different page, but the login page is same for both user.

Now i am using below code into spring-servlet.xml file . So please suggest me some solution on that.

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/airline/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/logout"
        authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
   <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSrc"
       users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from spring_users where username=?" 
       authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from spring_users u, spring_roles ur where u.user_id=ur.user_id and u.username=?"/>
   </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to control the navigation flow after a successful authentication, you can do so by adding your own AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Add the following attribute to your `<form-login> element` which refers to the customAuthenticationHandler bean,

```
<form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationHandler"/>
...
</http>
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationHandler" class="com.examples.CustomAuthenticationHandler" />
```

The CustomAuthenticationHandler class looks like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userTargetUrl = "/welcome.xhtml";
        String adminTargetUrl = "/admin/welcome.xhtml";
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, adminTargetUrl);
        }
        else if(roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, userTargetUrl);
        }
        else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            return;
        }
 }

}
```