# Spring Security - Can I use both namespace and filter-chain?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security and I have to use both filter-chain and namespace. Namespace works fine but it seems that the filter-chain doesn't!
Here is my configuration. First, namespace:

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<sec:http pattern="/app/login.jsp*" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/admin/login.jsp*" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/app/*.png" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/admin/*.png" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/app/**" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/app/login.jsp?aer=" />
    <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/app/j_spring_security_check"
        always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/app/index.html"
        login-page='/app/login.jsp' authentication-failure-url='/app/login.jsp?login_error' />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/app/j_spring_security_logout"
        invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/app/login.jsp" />
</sec:http>
<sec:http pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/admin/login.jsp?aer=" />
    <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check"
        always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/admin/index.html"
        login-page='/admin/login.jsp' authentication-failure-url='/admin/login.jsp?login_error' />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/admin/j_spring_security_logout"
        invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/admin/login.jsp" />
</sec:http>
```

This works fine. But I also need to have a filter-chain to check other requests. (These requests are dynamically being created and we have to control them this way)
This is my filter-chain:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">

    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/common/**" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/rest/**"
        filters="
        ConcurrentSessionFilter,
        securityContextPersistenceFilter,
        logoutFilter,
        authenticationProcessingFilter,
        sessionManagementFilter,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor" />

    </security:filter-chain-map> 
</bean>
```

The problem is, **the filter-chain does not control anything**. I'm sure that the filter-chain is working fine when namespaces are not used. But when I add namespaces, the problem begins.
Why? Can't I use that? or I can and I have to change something?

**UPDATED:**
This my debug log when calling this resource: `/rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp`

```
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher           - Checking match of request : '/rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp'; against '/app/login.jsp*'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher           - Checking match of request : '/rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp'; against '/admin/login.jsp*'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher           - Checking match of request : '/rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp'; against '/app/*.png'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher           - Checking match of request : '/rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp'; against '/admin/*.png'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher           - Checking match of request : '/rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp'; against '/app/**'
DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher           - Checking match of request : '/rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp'; against '/admin/**'
DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /rest/asrv/gtallmmbrsofusrgrp has no matching filters
```

Comment: From the way you're configuring the namespace, I'm assuming that you're using SS 3.1? Based on the specificity of your question, it seems like you know what you're doing with regards to configuration - are you trying to apply this filter chain *instead of* the <sec:http> namespace declarations, or in addition to them?

Comment: I'm trying to add these filters to the <sec:http> namespace.

Comment: I've update my question @PeterMularien . Now you can see that filter-chain-proxy does not work. Is it my configuration that causes this problem? Do I have to change the order?

Comment: From your silence, I'm assuming that this is not possible to use both namespaces and filter-chain. Right?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are missing the DelegatingFilterProxy entry in your web.xml. But anyways,

As of Spring 3.1, the FilterChainProxy is configured using a list of SecurityFilterChain instances and FilterChainMap is deprecated. So try configuring it this way:

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/common/**" filters="none" />
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none" />
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/rest/**"
                filters="
                ConcurrentSessionFilter,
                securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                logoutFilter,
                authenticationProcessingFilter,
                sessionManagementFilter,
                exceptionTranslationFilter,
                filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And add the filter to your web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

[API Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.html)

**UPDATE 1**:

To add logging to your application just put log4j jar on the path and add a log4j.properties file under your classpath.

Log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p %c %M - %m\n

log4j.category.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

See also [logging using Log4j](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging-log4j)

**UPDATE 2**: It seems to work for me, I have placed a test page welcome.xhtml in rest directory. The debug log is as follows:

```
2012-07-30 00:26:05,917 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher matches - Checking match of request : '/rest/welcome.xhtml'; against '/javax.faces.resource/**'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,923 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,923 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository readSecurityContextFromSession - No HttpSession currently exists
2012-07-30 00:26:05,923 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository loadContext - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2012-07-30 00:26:05,925 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,925 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,925 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,925 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,925 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,926 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,926 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,928 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter doFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,928 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,929 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter doFilter - Requested session IDD44EAA53A767F3DC9C7338D3CD335198 is invalid.
2012-07-30 00:26:05,929 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,929 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,929 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher matches - Checking match of request : '/rest/welcome.xhtml'; against '/login.xhtml'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,929 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher matches - Checking match of request : '/rest/welcome.xhtml'; against '/*'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,929 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher matches - Checking match of request : '/rest/welcome.xhtml'; against '/admin/**'
2012-07-30 00:26:05,930 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor beforeInvocation - Public object - authentication not attempted
2012-07-30 00:26:05,932 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy doFilter - /rest/welcome.xhtml reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2012-07-30 00:26:06,229 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter doFilter - Chain processed normally
```

I think it is the two form logins that you have is causing problems. Try to have only one login form and control the navigation after that based on the role. See this question for example: [Can i use one Login page to redirect different page with Spring 3.0 Security..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486222/can-i-use-one-login-page-to-redirect-different-page-with-spring-3-0-security/11488598)

Comment: I'd check that in the next few hours and let you know the result. But that's not much of me to forget this.

Comment: I checked your configuration, unfortunately this does not work either. And there are no logs as it is not encountering any problem. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I mean if you set the log level to debug you will see information about each request matcher and the filter applied to it.

Comment: How can I enable this debug log?

Comment: Updated the answer on how to add logging. Also post your output to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Now you can see that my filter-chain does not work at all.

Comment: From your silence, I'm assuming that this is not possible to use both namespaces and filter-chain. Right?

Comment: I didn't get time but I will give it a try myself and let you know.

Comment: Thanks.It doesn't take much time to set up such a thing. Please let me know the result.

Comment: Okay I did find it is working for me. I have attached my debug log to the answer. By the way why do you have two form logins, you should be having one login form and then redirect to the appropriate page based on the role. You can see an example of how to do this in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486222/can-i-use-one-login-page-to-redirect-different-page-with-spring-3-0-security/11488598#11488598         . Try fixing this..I will be back  in the morning.

Comment: As my application has two different panels for admin and user and those URLs are different I have to have two different login pages. Thank you Ravi, I'm testing my app once again. I'll tell you what happens.

Comment: Yet it's not working. I think I should use just one of these, not together.

Comment: Although the answer has not yet been found, but as a "thank you" I give you the bounty :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry I couldn't help you in the end.